# How does gcc/ld find zlib.so?

Tags: gcc, linker, shared-libraries, ld, zlib

I've used zlib for ages and never thought about the fact that it is named slightly unconventionally. While most libraries on Linux follow the naming convention of `lib<name>.so` for shared objects and `lib<name>.a` for archives, zlib is named `zlib.so`/`zlib.a`. My question is: how does gcc/ld know to look for `zlib.so` when I use `-lz` as a link flag?

I understand that for linking, gcc invokes ld, which searches for libraries in certain default paths and any path specified with `-L`, and it appends the `lib` and `.so` or `.a.` parts as necessary. Oddly, [gcc's manual page for linking options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) only mentions that the linker can find archives; there is no mention of the `.so` extension. The [man page for ld](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ld) at least mentions both extensions, but still only mentions searching by prepending `lib` to the specified library name. How does ld know to add the `lib` *after* the `z` for zlib? I've never seen this happen to another library.

Comment: It doesn't. It looks for `libz.so`, which is usually in `/lib` or `/lib64`, but might in some distributions actually be in `/usr/lib[64]`... If you have a `zlib.so` that applications are using, the applications are calling `dlopen()`, so the linking is not done by `ld` (or `ld.so`).

Comment: @twalberg, should that be an answer, not just a comment? You might've hit the nail on the head. However, when I've used zlib in building Matlab mex functions, I've had to use `-lzlib` and provide a `-L` path to a `zlib.so`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`gcc` has several different methods for linking libraries, shared or static. If you specify `-lz`, `gcc` is going to look for `libz.so` (possibly with some version bits between the `libz` and the `.so`, but the important part is the file name will start with `libz` and end with `.so`), or for `libz.a` (again, possibly with version info) if you are compiling statically, or as a fallback if the shared library does not exist. If you specify `-lzlib` it will look for `libzlib.so` (which is not the standard name - the package is often named `zlib`, but the library itself is `libz`). Another way of linking would be to not use the `-l<lib>` option, and just specify `/path/to/zlib.so` or `-L /path/to zlib.so` (or `zlib.a` if you want). In this case, the library doesn't have to have the `lib` prefix, but you would have to explicitly provide any version info, unless provisions are made for a symbolic link or something similar to provide the literal name `zlib.so`.

Applications can also load shared libraries at runtime via `dlopen()` and it's other associated functions, in which case the library can also be named whatever you want it to be (this doesn't work for static libraries, of course).

So, if the library you are looking at is actually called `zlib.so`, then it is not being found by `gcc ... -lz`, unless it just happens to be a symbolic link to `libz.so` (or vice versa, in which case `gcc` is really just using `libz.so`, which happens to have the same content as your `zlib.so`). However `gcc` might be using it if the build process explicitly names the library in the link stage (not using `-l<lib>`) or if your application loads it via `dlopen()` (but in that case, it's not really linked to your program - it's just loaded at run time).

Comment: Wow, can't believe I never noticed the `libz.so` variation before. You're right about all that. And it turns out that Matlab is smart enough to find `zlib.so` if you use `-zlib` because it searches for the library both with and without the prepended `lib`.

Comment: Oops, previous comment was supposed to say *if you use `-lzlib`*. That makes a difference!